# How to check if a polygon is empty in Shapely?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I'm pretty new to Python so the answer to this question is probably quite simple, but I've looked everywhere and tried a lot but couldn't find the answer.

Simplifying a polygon using Shapely may result in an empty polygon. I want to replace the polygon with a point if the polygon is empty. Something that would work like:

```
if mypoly is empty:
    mypoly = [(0,0)]
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Given that `mypoly` is a shapely polygon, you can check if it's empty using `is_empty` which is built in to Shapely to check for empty ones.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

if mypoly.is_empty:
    mypoly = Point(0, 0)
```