# An empty polygon generated with OpenTripPlanner generates error with .is_empty Shapely instruction

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, opentripplanner

I have an isochron polygon generated with OpenTripPlanner:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[]},"properties":{"time":-47},"id":"fid--576b228b_15b66d32d71_-7cbd"}]}
```

This polygon is translated as a Shapely object with the following instruction:

```
isochrone = shapely.geometry.asShape(isochroneJSON['features'][0]['geometry'])
```

This is how it looks like in Spyder:

```
{u'type': u'FeatureCollection', u'features': [{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': []}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'time': -47}, u'id': u'fid--576b228b_15b66d32d71_-7a54'}]}
```

It really looks like an empty polygon to me. My problem is that I want to exclude it from the rest of my treatment and to check if it is valid and/or empty. And the following instruction:

```
if not isochrone.is_empty:
```

Generates an error with .is_empty shapely instruction:

```
return (self._geom is None) or bool(self.impl['is_empty'](self))
self.__geom__, n = self.factory(self.context)
```

And I am completely lost because [the only similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795959/how-to-check-if-a-polygon-is-empty-in-python-using-shapely) seems to not have my own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty geometries are a bit tricky, in your particular case (MultiPolygons), you could partially fix it by using `shape` instead of `asShape`:

```
import json
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, shape, mapping, asShape

Q = shape({'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': []})
print(Q.is_empty)
print(Q.geom_type)
print(json.dumps(mapping(Q)))
```

this outputs (the `geom_type` is in the case of empty multipolygon indeed not equal to `MultiPolygon`):

```
True
GeometryCollection
{"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": []}
```

Comment: In my case just using 'shape' instead of 'asShape' has removed the error. But don't ask me why!!